# Filter out Records Based on Two Keys of Interchangeable Order

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am creating a private messaging system for part of a client project.

I am storing each message as a record with the values for `from` as the ID of the sender, `to` as the ID of the receiver, and `message` as the message text.

I would like to have a page in which users can view a list of other users that they have a messaging thread with. I am retrieving all relevant messages that the user is a sender or receiver of:

```
$thisProfile = Auth::user()->profile_id;

$messages = DB::table('messages')
    ->where('from', '=', $thisProfile)
    ->orWhere('to', '=', $thisProfile)
    ->get();

return view('messages.all', compact('messages'));
```

However, that is obviously returning records where the same two users are mentioned. Below are some example records that I am getting when logged in as user 1:

```
#1 - from: 1, to: 2
#2 - from: 2, to: 1
#3 - from: 1, to: 2
#4 - from: 4, to: 1
#5 - from: 1, to: 4
#6 - from: 9, to: 1
```

I would like to filter out the records where the same two users have been retrieved before. In this case, the results should look like:

```
#1 - from: 1, to: 2
#4 - from: 4, to: 1
#6 - from: 9, to: 1
```

The closest I have got is finding the `unique()` method used with collections, which filters out records for either `to` or `from` in one order.

How can I filter out records, based on the two keys `to` and `from`, where they are of interchangeable order?

Comment: Hi, I really don't know what you want to do from your description... But there is [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) that may be in help for you.

Comment: Is there only a `messages` table or also something like `conversations`? Because only from what you posted, this makes totally sense in my opinion, because each message is unique and the query will also not return the same message twice...

Comment: @Namoshek I was trying to avoid having two tables, but do you think that would be the best way?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what exactly you want to achieve. From what you wrote, it isn't really clear (yet).

Comment: @Namoshek I'm sorry about that, it's a pretty hard concept to explain. I will have a go using the `conversations` table. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't be so sure about that. You can still try to explain what you are up to.

Comment: @Namoshek which bit don't you understand? I can then edit that part of the question.

Comment: What relations to the `Message` model have you defined on your `User` model? I guess something like `messagesFrom` and `messagesTo`?

Comment: @Namoshek `messageFrom` and `messageTo`, both one-to-one.

Comment: Why one-to-one? They should be one-to-many, if one `User` can send many `Messages`.

Comment: @Namoshek sorry, yes you are correct, I just saw the `belongsTo`, I didn't think, and typed one-to-one, I am using one-to-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I finally understood what you are up to and this is what I would suggest you to do.

Expecting that you have separate relations for `messagesFrom` (the ones the user sent) and `messagesTo` (the ones they received), you should be able to use this query:

```
$thisProfile = Auth::user()->profile_id;

$users = User::whereHas('messagesFrom', function ($messages) use ($thisProfile) {
        $messages->where('to', $thisProfile);
    })
    ->orWhereHas('messagesTo', function ($messages) use ($thisProfile) {
        $messages->where('from', $thisProfile);
    })
    ->get();
```

Loading the latest `Message` of a conversation for a preview could be a neat thing as well, but this sounds like it was enough for a whole other question.